# Merge two Tables and sort

Tags: google-sheets

I have two tables in two different sheets of my Google Spreadsheet that contain the same information. I now want to have a third sheet where I combine these two tables into one and sort them by a column.

Is there a way to achieve that that is not manually adding the second range at the end of the first range of data?

Comment: Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Answer (score 0):

Providing you have your column headers in the first row, this script should work perfectly.

I have tried to explain every step I am taking but if theres anything that does not work or you do not understand let me know.

I am new to scripts myself but this is one I have written a few times.

```
function merge() {
  //Start by getting the ID of the first spreadsheet you wish to copy from and also make sure to change the sheet name
 var s1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("place ID here").getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  //Now do the same for the second sheet you wish to copy from
 var s2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("place ID here").getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  //Again for the sheet you wish to copy to
 var s3 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Place ID here").getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  //Now we are going to define the ranges we wish to copy as so, row,column,row,column, these are numeric so starting with A1 and finsihing with C2 would be 1,1,2,3
  //I am going to assume you want to start with A2 and collect all the data you have on the sheet

var r1 = s1.getRange(2,1,s1.getLastRow(),s1.getLastColumn()).getValues()
var r2 = s2.getRange(2,1,s2.getLastRow(),s2.getLastColumn()).getValues()

//Now we will paste that data, starting at the last blank row
var p1 = s3.getRange(2,1,s1.getLastRow(),s1.getLastColumn()).setValues(r1)
var p2 = s3.getRange(s3.getLastRow(),1,s2.getLastRow(),s2.getLastColumn()).setValues(r2)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following formulas

To import the data from two spreadsheets use import range on two sheets, example below,

```
=importrange("pasteYourUrlHere","Sheet1!A2:J")
```

Then on the third sheet we can merge the two sheets and filter by column A using a filter function, see example below

```
={filter(Sheet1!A7:J, len(Sheet1!A7:A)); filter(Sheet2!A7:K, len(Sheet2!A7:A))
```